# How to extract text including inline elements and the xpath to that element of the HTML page in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml

I am working on a Django project where I need to extract all the text-containing elements and the xPath to that element. e.g:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        The Demo page
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <section>
            <h1> Hello world
            </h1>
        </section>
        <div>
            <p>
                Hope you all are doing well,
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                <span>This is the</span> example HTML
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output should be something like:

```
/head/title: The Demo Page
/body/div/section/h1: Hello world!
/body/div/div[1]/p: Hope you all are doing well,
/body/div/div[2]/p: <span>This is the</span> example HTML
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   import xmltodict
import json
def flatten_json(y):
    #creates Xpath for each tag with counts
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + "/")
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + "/")
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name] = x
    flatten(y)
    print(out)

with open("test_django.html") as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
output_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(doc))
flatten_json(output_dict)
```

the above code have given me following output:

{'html/head/title/': 'The Demo page',
'html/body/div/section/h1/': 'Hello world',
'html/body/div/div/0/p/': 'Hope you all are doing well,', 'html/body/div/div/1/p/span/': 'This is the',
'html/body/div/div/1/p/#text/': 'example HTML'}

For span tag if you want to display in different way then you have to add your own logic accordingly